# Как перейти на тёмную тему в Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio

Где можно найти файл настроек для VS 2008 (`.vssettings`), который сменил бы тему на тёмную? Не только окно редактирования кода, а вообще все цвета в студии. Хотелось бы видеть тему, аналогичную тёмной теме в VS 2015 или 2019.

P.S. Прошу, не предлагайте перейти на более новую версию VS. Будь у меня такая возможность, давно бы это уже сделал.

Comment: Просто из интереса: что мешает вам обновиться?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, требование заказчика.

Comment: В таком случае соболезную

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, что это возможно сделать используя только опции `.vssettings`. Вероятным ответом на ваш вопрос будет полная замена ресурсов Windows (включая иконки) на тему, например, такую: https://winzoro.net/2017/03/08/photoshopf.html . Я не даю полных гарантий, что авторы этих DLL чисты на руку. Лучше всего собрать эти библиотеки самостоятельно используя редакторы ресурсов, такие как [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.ru/pe-explorer-resource-editor.htm) или [Resource Builder](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Builder). Но велика вероятность, что в тех DLL нет вредоносного кода, и всё будет работать так, как задумано. Но, разумеется, это тоже требует проверки. Так что лучше для начала собрать на тестовой виртуальной машине.

Кстати, вы удивитесь, но для тех же операций в Windows 98 достаточно было просто зайти в настройки и настроить тему окон и иконок без замен системных библиотек. Эти настройки частично остались в Windows XP, но совсем пропали в Windows Vista.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это изменит тему всей ОС?

Comment: Я думаю, это всё-таки можно сделать через `.vssettings`, т.к. однозначно есть возможность настроить это вручную. Здесь вопрос во времязатратах, потому и спрашиваю о готовом решении.

Comment: @V-Mor Эту тему обсуждали в [треде на MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd73462f-6e13-4634-9dc2-8f275720334d/visual-studio-2008-environment-color-settings-to-duplicate-expression-suite-3-dark-theme?forum=vssetup). Там пришли к выводу, что это возможно только в VS2010+.

Comment: Тогда это очень странно. "Ручками" настроить явно можно, ибо есть возможность настроить цвета всех элементов VS по отдельности. Что тогда мешало какому-нибудь энтузиасту заморочиться на денёк, подогнать все цвета и экспортировать всё сие в файл?.. Не понятно.

Comment: @V-Mor А вы найдите этот файл, цвета в xml можно заменить пакетно.

Comment: Вот я как раз и прошу помощи в поиске данного файла. Если я Вас правильно понял.

Comment: Ну вот весь прикол в том, что был бы любой файл, тему можно получить пропустив все цвета последовательно через фильтры svg `invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg) contrast(90%)`. Вопрос лишь в том, существуют ли эти файлы в природе, или VS2008 они обошли стороной...

Comment: Там ведь можно импортировать и экспортировать настройки из файлов. Значит не обошли.

Comment: Темной темы добиться можно, например, на любом сайте в devtools в консоли браузера вставив одну строчку `document.body.style.filter='invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg) contrast(90%)'`. Но, к сожалению или к счастью, VS2008 был на движке `.NET 3.5` а не на `electron` как последние версии VS.

Comment: Если вопрос еще актуален, экспортируйте мне настройки, выложите в вопросе, я применю фильтры ко всем цветам.

Comment: Я попробовал экспортировать настройки, но там нет прямого указания цветов.